# SSIS Lookup transformation for Comparing two tables

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

I'm using Lookup transformation to compare two tables from different server.  I want to add lookup column values as well in the destination no match output table as shown below. For example Table 1 is my table where i need to check for bad data.

```
ID  | Name  | Address
--------------------------
 1  | Ramya | 01 - London
--------------------------
 2  | Vidya | India
```

Below is my Lookup table

```
ID  | Name  | Address
--------------------------
 1  | Ramya | London
--------------------------
 22  | Vidy | India
```

I want my destination (another new table) to have data with unmatched rows

```
ID  | Name  | Address      | LID    | LName   |  LAddress 
---------------------------------------------------------
 1  | Ramya | 01 - London  | NULL   | NULL    |  London
---------------------------------------------------------
 22  | Vidy | India        | 2     | Vidya    |  NULL
```

or something like this::

```
ID  | Name  | Address      | Mismatch|
-------------------------------------
 1  | Ramya | 01 - London  | Address: London | 
-------------------------------------
 22  | Vidy | India        | ID: 2 and Name: Vidya|
```

Comment: Is there a primary key on each table? If so what is/are the keys?

Comment: @MiguelH ID is the primary key In the table

Comment: It would probably be better to use SSIS to copy the remote table to the local server, then compare them in SQL.

Comment: Or instead of a lookup, you can use both tables as a source and do a merge-join.

Comment: @TabAlleman I used a Merge join and combined two tables. I got both tables rows in my destination table.  Now how I should perform Comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Could you identify the non matched records prior to processing in the SSIS.
Here's some SQL to create your example data and provide Matched/Non matched records. The SSIS could then process the unmatched records and do additional lookups using Name to see if these have a match. However, this would likely have multiple matches!

```
create table #temp1(
id1 integer,MyName1 varchar(50),MYaddress1 varchar(50)
)
create table #temp2(id2 integer,MyName2 varchar(50),MYaddress2 varchar(50)
)
insert into #temp1  (id1,Myname1,myaddress1)
values (1,'Ramya','01 - London')
insert into #temp1  (id1,Myname1,myaddress1)
values (2,'Vidya','India')
select * from #temp1

insert into #temp2  (id2,Myname2,myaddress2)
values (1,'Ramya','London')
insert into #temp2  (id2,Myname2,myaddress2)
values (22,'Vidya','India')
select * from #temp2
;
with mycte1 as
(SELECT 
a.id1,a.myName1,a.MyAddress1,b.id2,b.myName2 as LName,b.myAddress2 as LAddress,
'No Match' as Match
from #temp1 a left join #temp2 b
on a.myname1 = b.myname2 and 
a.myAddress1 = b.myAddress2
where b.myaddress2 is null or b.myname2 is null
),
mycte2 as
(SELECT a.id1,a.myName1,a.MyAddress1,b.id2,b.myNAme2 as LName,
b.myAddress2 as LAddress,'Match' as Match
from #temp1 a inner join #temp2 b
on a.myname1 = b.myname2 and 
a.myAddress1 = b.myAddress2
)
select *  from mycte2
union 
select * from mycte1

drop table #temp1
drop table #temp2
```